# bootstrap doesn't align in only one page

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I use bootstrap 4 in my page and I do this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>"GO"</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="back()">Back</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
```

I want display the `("GO" and button)` but I see the component display in tis way:

```
GO
button
```

How is it possibile and only in one page in the other it works fine. ANyone can help me?

Comment: Keep them in the same <div>, <div> is a block element, meaning takes full row.

Comment: .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}                                             Try this custom CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>"GO"</label>           
      <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="back()">Back</button> 
    </div>                
   <div class="col-md-6">

   </div>
 </div>
```